# How to use __builtin_clzll in Rust?

Tags: rust

GCC has the `__builtin_clzll` builtin function that according to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/builtin-functions-gcc-compiler/:

```
__builtin_clz(x): This function is used to count the leading zeros of the integer. Note : clz = count leading zero’s
```

I think LLVM also has these functions, and Rust is compiled with LLVM. Is there a way to use this function in Rust?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust has the [`leading_zeros`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u32.html#method.leading_zeros) method on all built-in integer types. And if compiled on a CPU supporting an efficient hardware leading zeros instruction it will use that:

```rust
pub fn foo(n: u32) -> u32 {
    n.leading_zeros()
}
```

`rustc -O -C target-cpu=broadwell`:

```
example::foo:
  lzcnt eax, edi
  ret
```

`rustc -O --target arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf -C target-cpu=cortex-a76`:

```
example::foo:
  clz r0, r0
  bx lr
```

Comment: This answers the "how do you do <this very specific thing>", but the more general answer is that (some?) builtins (LLVM, not GCC, but they largely overlap) are available on nightly through [`std::intrinsics`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/intrinsics/index.html).